# How to unit test GraphQL responses on Lumen?

Tags: json, api, phpunit, graphql, lumen

I'm trying to test an API I built with `Lumen (PHP)`, but I'm stuck on `unit test` my `GraphQL` responses`.

This is what I have tried:

```php
class MovieQueryTest extends Tests\GraphQLTestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function testCanSearch()
    {
        Movie::create([
            'name' => 'Fast & Furious 8',
            'alias' => 'Fast and Furious 8',
            'year' => 2016
        ]);

        $response = $this->post('/graphql/v1', [
            'query' => '{movies(search: "Fast & Furious"){data{name}}}'
        ]);

        $response->seeJson([
            'data' => [
                'movies' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'name' => 'Fast & Furious 8'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is what I got:

> PHPUnit 7.5.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> F.....                                                              6
>   / 6 (100%)
>
> Time: 690 ms, Memory: 24.00 MB
>
> There was 1 failure:
>
> 1) MovieQueryTest::testCanSearch Unable to find JSON fragment
>   ["data":{"movies":{"data":{"name":"Fast & Furious"}}}] within
>   [{"data":{"movies":{"data":[]}}}]. Failed asserting that false is
>   true.

The problem is that my data structure doesn't match the `JSON's` structure. While my data is inside an `Array`, the JSON's data is inside an `Object` and I can't figure out how to make it match:

- `["data":{"movies":{"data":{"name":"Fast & Furious 8"}}}]`
- `[{"data":{"movies":{"data":[{"name":"Fast & Furious 8"}]}}}]`

How can I make my data structure match the JSON's data structure or there is a better way to unit test GraphQL responses on Lumen?

Comment: e200, please let us know if the answer below helped or if you require further assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap `'name' => 'Fast & Furious 8'` inside it's own array, for example:

The following:

```
$array = [
    'data' => [
        'movies' => [
            'data' => [
                ['name' => 'Fast & Furious 8']
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Should output:

```
{"data":{"movies":{"data":[{"name":"Fast & Furious 8"}]}}}
```